# LM350 variable voltage regulator SNAFU

Tags: power-supply, lm317, linear-regulator

My LM350 regulator with smoothing caps (C1:0.33uF, C2:1uF polarized, R1:150 R2:10ohms+trimpot) does not work. It works without capacitors. I am an idiot. What have I done wrong? I tested all the connections, and they match up fine with the diagram. On Vout, there is briefly a nice voltage, then it drops. When I retest with my DMM a few moments later, the voltage is up again, then it drops.

[image: Diagram]

[image: Top]

[image: Bottom]

What is wrong? Hit my stupid skull with your cluebats!

Edit: Had the same problem with a LM317 voltage regulator. I 'fixed' it by removing the caps. But I really want to know what I'm doing wrong here. The LM350 is confirmed working - without those caps.

Edit2: This question has been answered by @sstobbe. I had a bad solderjoint in an inconspicuous location. Thanks for your time everyone.

[image: Working regulator]

Comment: Does the regulator get hot with no load and the capacitor?

Comment: No, it is quite cool.

Comment: There is most certainly no short, either. I feed it 12V@20A. There would be a smoke signal.

Comment: The way you have C2 in there looks odd - it is hard tp tell, but do you have the negative side connected to ground?  Try removing only C2.  If it then works, turn C2 around and reconnect it then see if it still works.

Comment: Is C2 confirmed good?

Comment: Yes, C2 is confirmed good. Unsoldered it and powered the circuit. No output, the LM350 just heated up quickly.

Comment: @JRE You are a gem. I had connected the negative pin to ground. I'll turn it around. It looks like it should be facing ground in the diagram, but I am not used to polarized caps.

Comment: Use a _new_ C2 if it was installed wrong side up.  You've hurt its feelings by making it run backwards, and will seek revenge - when the moment it right.

Comment: The negative pin on C2 goes to ground.  I wanted you to make sure it s connected that way.

Comment: @JRE :/ Hope was the last evil to escape Pandora's box.

Comment: @user2497 - The negative pin is SUPPOSED to go to ground. Or did  you mean to say that you had connected the positive pin?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast It was connected correctly.

Comment: R1 & R2 are constantly loading the output so adding a DMM and then the voltage drops is suspicious, its likely a bad solder joint somewhere or its oscillating

Comment: @sstobbe Yes, I suspect cold soldering somewhere, I was in a hurry. I will redo all the joints.

Comment: @sstobbe Please post this as an answer. Thanks. I am embarrassed, of course ;)

Comment: @user2497 Cold solder joints happen to all the time, glad you were able to resolve your issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resistors R1 & R2 are constantly loading the output. So, having the output voltage sage due to probing the output with a DMM is suspicious.

Its likely a bad solder joint somewhere. When you apply pressure with the DMM probes, you break a connection.

It could also be that the output is oscillating and the impedance of you holding the probes plus meter is sufficient to detune whatever is oscillating.

Answer (score 0):

You only need a load.  The LM devices are "series pass" and can only increase the voltage (by supplying current) but can't decrease it by sinking it; a load has to pull the cap down if it is too high.

Comment: I tried a voltmeter that pulls ~30mA. Not enough?

Comment: Is this the explanation for the shifting voltage potential I read with my DMM?

Comment: Should be enough.  What output voltage are you aiming for?

Comment: 9 volts. I saw it rise and fall with my DMM, testing it every few seconds.

Comment: What is the voltage at the adj pin?